# Create a paint like work area and ability to move them

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, mfc

I like to  design a workplace or form(not decided) in VC++ (MFC) or (C++) where I can select and place different objects like car , bike etc and move them programmatically.Each object has its own properties(which is already designed) I have no problem in moving them by changing x,y position.

But my question is how do I place  different objects like car , bus on screen and move them to the place I want.I should also able to delete them when needed. As I am new MFC I would like to know how to proceed . Given an right direction I can swim on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is an excellent framework for this kind of thing.

Comment: hey thanks for your input .After reading few inputs I think QT will be best solution .could you give few suggestion on how do I create a editor to put images like car,bus in QT and also could you suggest some good web reference

Comment: Well, you wouldn't need an editor as such. Start with a book. (Advanced Qt Programming: Creating Great Software with C++ and Qt 4). Download the Qt framework. Work through the examples. http://qt.nokia.com has all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use MFC. Period. That thing is a genuine piece of crap, and every programmer I know absolutely hates it and stays away from it.

If you want to start from scratch, use WINAPI, but that's your choice (depending on if you want to reinvent the wheel.) Read up on input events and DirectDraw (for drawing to a 2D canvas.) Microsoft also has WPF for newer .NET builds, and it has canvas support built it.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that you should not use MFC. Sticking with C++, there is Managed C++ on the .NET platform, or you could go native C++ and use DirectDraw or use OpenGL (which is more cross platform).